# Kubernetes Autoscale Based on Custom-Metrics on v2alpha

Tags: kubernetes

I have a 4 node k8 cluster using Kargo (Kubernetes v1.6.1+coreos.0) and was hoping to use autoscaling/v2alpha1. When I do `kubectl api-version` I only see autoscaling/v1. So I tried to add  `--runtime-config=apis/autoscaling/v2alpha1` config to `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.manifest`. But this would result in my apiserver shutting down.

Q1. How can I add the new autoscaling/v2alpha api set to my current cluster? Is there a way to only install/upgrade (I am thinking `kubectl apply something`) the api without upgrading the entire cluster?

Q2. Is it possible to get autoscaling based on custom metrics running with `autoscale/v1` in 1.6+? With `autoscale/v1`, I am able to get cpu based autoscale working correctly with Heapster. The [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) say support for annotations was removed in v1.6 in favor of the autoscaling/v2alpha1.

Comment: Maybe this article helps you to find a solution for Q2. https://medium.com/@marko.luksa/kubernetes-autoscaling-based-on-custom-metrics-without-using-a-host-port-b783ed6241ac

Comment: I did look into that article. Though the metrics are getting into heapster, the hpa is not scaling based on the custom metrics. I was hoping to confirm if it is because annotation based hpa scaling in autoscale/v1 is disabled i K8 1.6 (that is how I understood from the k8 doc; if you have to use custom metrics in 1.6, you have to use autoscale/v2alpha1)

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem and just solved it! In my k8s 1.6.1 cluster, I added:

```
--runtime-config=apis/autoscaling/v2alpha1
```

to `/opt/kubernates/manifests/kube-apisever.yaml`, and then run the following command:

```
systemctl restart kubelet
```

After that you will see `v2alhpa1` in the api-version lists.